# find no consumer in Kafka consumer group but consume is normal

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use kafka which version is `kafka V0.11`.
I have a consumer group which `group.id = test`, but when I use command like `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group test --describe`, I find no consumer under this group.
however, service consume is normal.
Who could know why? thx.

Comment: Is your consumer using Zookeeper or Kafka to connect?

Comment: use Kafka in consumer.

Comment: Do you have auto offset commits disabled and are not commiting any offsets to any group?

Comment: I set enable.auto.commit = false, actually one consumer in group has consumed and commit offsets async to kafka. I know this as I log while consumer commits offsets.

Comment: Are you able to share your code as a [mcve]?